# Razor Page Cascade Datatables by Dropdown

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

i have a dropdown list and i want to reload the datatable once i change the dropdown please note that the Checkbox field postback the page as well to update the database below is the cs file and will post the cshtml after

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IpponAcademy.Models.IJAContext _context;
        public List<SelectListItem> judokaGroupList { get; set; }
       
        [BindProperty]
        public Boolean IsAttend { get; set; }

        

        public IList<tbl_Judoka> tbl_Judoka { get;set; }
        public IndexModel(IpponAcademy.Models.IJAContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public void OnGet(Guid? id)
        {
            var GroupList = _context.LK_Groups.ToList();
            judokaGroupList = GroupList.Select(a =>
                                  new SelectListItem
                                  {
                                      Value = a.Group_GUID.ToString(),
                                      Text = a.Group_Name
                                  }).OrderBy(t => t.Text).ToList();

            if (id == null)
            {
                id = Guid.Parse("7F299B82-3397-40F2-8105-65AECB1BA2A8"); //Group A
            }
            tbl_Judoka = _context.tbl_Judokas.Where(c => c.tbl_Judoka_Groups.Any(o => o.Is_Active == true && o.Group_GUID == id)).Include(c => c.tbl_Judoka_Groups.Where(o => o.Is_Active == true && o.Group_GUID == id)).ToList();

        }

        public void OnGetJudoka(Guid? id)
        {
            var GroupList = _context.LK_Groups.ToList();
            judokaGroupList = GroupList.Select(a =>
                                  new SelectListItem
                                  {
                                      Value = a.Group_GUID.ToString(),
                                      Text = a.Group_Name
                                  }).OrderBy(t => t.Text).ToList();

            if (id == null)
            {
                id = Guid.Parse("7F299B82-3397-40F2-8105-65AECB1BA2A8"); //Group A
            }
            
            tbl_Judoka = _context.tbl_Judokas.Where(c => c.tbl_Judoka_Groups.Any(o => o.Is_Active == true && o.Group_GUID == id)).Include(c => c.tbl_Judoka_Groups.Where(o => o.Is_Active == true && o.Group_GUID == id)).ToList();

        }
    }
```

below is the cshtml file, I'd appreciate finding a simple way to do refresh the datatable with the new selected field from the dropdown

```
@page
@model IpponAcademy.Pages.Attendance.IndexModel

        
        @{
            ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
            Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }
        
        
        <form method="post">
       
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Group</label>
                <select id="ddlGroup" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.judokaGroupList"></select>
                @*onchange="alert(@Model.judokaGroupList)"*@
            </div>
        
            <table id="taskDt" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Attended
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Code
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Image
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Judoka
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.tbl_Judoka)
                    {
                        var imagePath = @"UploadedFiles/" + item.J_Image;
                        <tr>
                            <td>
        
                                <input type="hidden" name="J_GUID" id="J_GUID" value="@item.J_GUID" />
        
                                <input asp-for="IsAttend" name="IsAttend" id="IsAttend" type="checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit()" />
        
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.J_Code)
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
        
                                <img src="@imagePath" alt="Judoka" width="50" height="50" class="rounded-circle mr-1" onclick="return LoadDiv(this.src);" style="cursor: pointer" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.J_Name)
                            </td>
        
                        </tr>
                    }
                   
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </form>

        @section scripts{
            <script>
        
                var table;
                function LoadData() {
                    //alert('in');
                    table = $("#taskDt").DataTable({
                        
                        paging: true,
                        responsive: true,
                        searching: true,
                        ordering: true,
                        order: [[1, "asc"]]
                    });
                }
        
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    LoadData();
                    
                })
                $("#ddlGroup").change(function () {
                    alert('DDLGroup');
                    //table.ajax.url("/Attendance/Index?handler=GET&Id=" + $("#ddlGroup Option:Selected").val()).load();
                    window.location.href = '/Attendance/Index?handler=Judoka&Id=' + $("#ddlGroup Option:Selected").val();
                    });

        </script>
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `window.location.href` has been a simple enough way to refresh the datatable.Just one thing you need to improve,`OnGet` and `OnGetJudoka` method are the same,why not using just one method.

Change:

```
$("#ddlGroup").change(function () {
      window.location.href = '/Attendance/Index?handler=Judoka&Id=' + $("#ddlGroup Option:Selected").val();
});
```

To:

```
$("#ddlGroup").change(function () {
      window.location.href = '/Attendance/Index?Id=' + $("#ddlGroup Option:Selected").val();
});
```

If you must **use another way**,you could use `form.submit()`:

**Note**:Be sure add `name="id"`,otherwise the parameter will not bind to the backend.

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Judoka">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Group</label>
        <select id="ddlGroup" class="form-control" name="id" asp-items="Model.judokaGroupList" 
                                                   onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>         
    </div>
</form>
```

Backend code:

Change:

```
public void OnGetJudoka(Guid? id)
```

To:

```
public void OnPostJudoka(Guid? id)
```

BTW,I also have a suggestion that you'd better maintain the selected value after postback :

```
public void OnGetJudoka(Guid? id)
{
    var GroupList = _context.LK_Groups.ToList();
    judokaGroupList = GroupList.Select(a =>
                            new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = a.Group_GUID.ToString(),
                                Text = a.Group_Name
                            }).OrderBy(t => t.Text).ToList();
    //maintain the selected value after post back...
    var selectedValue= judokaGroupList.Where(a => a.Value == id.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
    selectedValue.Selected = true;
    
    //...

}
```